# Why can't I define both a default attribute value and use=required for the same attibute in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

[Section 3.2.3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cAttribute_Declarations) of the W3C XML Schema recommendation specifies that if "default" and "use" are both present in an attribute definition, "use" must have the actual value "optional".

I don't understand why. What's so bad about something like xs:attribute name="..." type="..." use="required" default="xy"? How can I model something like "attribute cant be missing and has a default-value of "xy"?

Answer (score 3):

Default value will be never used when use="required", so is superfluous. It is not conceptually wrong, just useless.

Comment: So how to set a specific value for the attribute? Like xs:attribute name="..." type="..." use="required" fixed="xy" but still left open the opportunity to change this value?

Comment: probably i have a wrong understanding of the "default" attribute?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_attribute.asp says "Attributes can have either a default value OR a fixed value specified. A default value is automatically assigned to the attribute when no other value is specified." What does this actually mean? Form my understanding the xsd only defines whats a valid intance is. So when this automatic asignment is happening?!

Comment: @terkel The automatic default value assignment is done when the document is parsed with a validating parser. Parser notes that the attribute is missing in the document but the schema has a default value for this attribute. Then the parser will pass on the element as it would have that attribute with the defined default value. Quote from the spec: "When an XML processor encounters an element without a specification for an attribute for which it has read a default value declaration, it MUST report the attribute with the declared default value to the application."

Comment: @terkel fixed value can't be changed, you can keep opportunity to change value by defining xs:attribute name="..." type="..." use="optional" default="xy". Default value is taken unless is overriden in xml file.

Comment: It's not correct that default + required would be superfluous. In some situations required + default  actually would be useful, e.g. if XML is generated out of an XSD-Schema. Actually I missed this feature already more than once.

Answer (score 1):

The default value defines what value the attribute takes if it is omitted from the document being validated. If it cannot be omitted from the document being validated, there is no point specifying a default.

Comment: I quite not understand the practical effect of the default-vaule. Since there will be no framework (like emf or so) which will modify an xml instance just by validating it, i.e. before validating a xml instance the attribute is missing and after a validate the attribute is set to the default value by the framework. At least i doubt a framework will do such things...
So when the attribute take the default value? At validation running time? So is it possible to model attribute based dependencies in an xsd? Make that sense? Is there a meaningfull example of using the default attribute?